# How to limit number of consumers on an ActiveMQ JMS queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We are using ActiveMQ and we're looking for a way to enforce a single-consumer policy for some of our JMS Queues. I've spent some time Googling but I can't find any way to limit the number of consumers on a queue.

Either of the following would be good solutions for us:

- A way to specify a maximum number of active consumers on a queue (in our case 1).
- A way to interrogate ActiveMQ to see if any consumers are already active for a queue before creating a new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting on broker side to enforce such a thing. You can, however, in all clients use the exclusive consumer option. That would allow all consumers to connect, but only one will actually get all messages until it drops out and a new exclusive consumer is chosen.

If you intend to host some sort of AMQ cloud service and really want to ensure applications out of your control behave according to SLA then you have to do some coding. You can implement ActiveMQ plugins.

If you implement a plugin and create a [BrokerFilter](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerFilter.html) then you can override the `addConsumer? method. Take a look at the [RuntimeConfigurationPlugin](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-runtime-config/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/plugin/RuntimeConfigurationPlugin.java) to see how to setup the plugin.

Please not that implementing a plugin is not an easy admin tweak but requires some work.

Comment: We control the entire ecosystem. The AMQ brokers, the producers, and the consumer are all our own applications and infrastructure. So I'm not concerned about supporting unknown applications. However, due to some limitations in our problem domain we run the risk of creating more than 1 message consumer per queue and we want to prevent that from happening.

Are you aware of any mechanism for interrogating AMQ about existing consumers for a queue? I believe it must be possible since you can view details about the consumers in the AMQ admin pages.

Thanks